# Fragment Activity "getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" on Default MapsActivity

Tags: android

How can I use

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

on default MapsActivity that is Fragment Activity?

Comment: What is not working with that?

Comment: getSupportActionBar()  not resolve

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve] with an [edit] to the question

Answer (score 1):

In Fragment, you need to call the activity first:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```